# How to get a debug log for a REST service in a managed package?

Tags: managed-package, debugging, debug-logs

I have an error that occurs somewhere in a REST service in my managed package. I've been trying for hours to get some kind of debug log out of the subscriber Org but to no avail. Whenever I fire a REST request from the outside of the Org and the log entry pops up in my Developer Console - it's just empty.

Has anybody managed to get some information in a situation like this? If so - how?

Comment: Have you engaged support to enable ISV logging? By default, logs don't show the execution of managed coffee to protect IP. You have to specifically request this feature.

Comment: @sfdcfox I thought that logging in through the License Management App would allow writing a debug log for the managed package. For some reason, this doesn't seem to work when making a REST request.

Comment: Basically this: [Troubleshooting in Subscriber Organizations](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/apex_debugging_sub_org.htm)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what changed but it seems it was somehow related to some configuration changes in the debug log. This was the only change I made and suddenly I'm getting the information that I want. I will update this answer if I can figure out what exactly did have this effect.